# Drawing audio as sound bars on a canvas does not overwrite last drawing when canvas.height not set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, audiocontext

I have the following in which I get an audioBuffer audio clip and then I draw a circle of sound bars to visualize it:

```
const { audioContext, analyser } = this.getAudioContext();
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = this.props.audioBuffer;
analyser.fftSize = 256;
source.connect(analyser).connect(audioContext.destination);

source.start();

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// find the center of the window
let center_x = canvas.width / 2;
let center_y = canvas.height / 2;
let  radius = 150;

const frequency_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequency_array);

const bars = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const bar_width = 2;

animationLooper();

function animationLooper(){
    //canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    // find the center of the window
    center_x = canvas.width / 2;
    center_y = canvas.height / 2;
    radius = 50;

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequency_array);
    for(let i = 0; i < bars; i++){

        //divide a circle into equal parts
        let rads = Math.PI * 2 / bars;

        const bar_height = frequency_array[i] / 2;

        // set coordinates
        let x = center_x + Math.cos(rads * i) * (radius);
        let y = center_y + Math.sin(rads * i) * (radius);
        const x_end = center_x + Math.cos(rads * i)*(radius + bar_height);
        const y_end = center_y + Math.sin(rads * i)*(radius + bar_height);

        //draw a bar
        drawBar(x, y, x_end, y_end, bar_width);

    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLooper);
}

function drawBar(x1, y1, x2, y2, width){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#1890ff";
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"  />
```

This results in this after audio finished playing and the drawing completes. It should return back to no blue lines.

[image: wrongSoundBars]

However if I comment in the line

```
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Then it correctly visualizes the audio and at the end the blue lines disappear. But I want a fixed height and width for my canvas. The end result should be lines/sound bars coming out from a center circle.

Does anyone know why the blue lines dont disappear when audio finished playing when I dont have that line commented in?

Comment: Setting the canvas size resets the 2D context state and clears the canvas. If you add the line `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);` will clear the canvas without the overhead of resenting the 2D context state. BTW `window `is the global this, its use is redundant in every instance you use it. You don't use it for most globals eg `document`, `source` both of which are global eg `window.document`,  and `window.source` so why use it for a select few.

Comment: ah i see. that makes sense. thanks! that clearRect also fixes it.

Comment: also maybe a side question @Blindman67 but in the image I posted you notice the bars are mostly coming out from the right and bottom. Do you have any tips to even it out more around the middle circle?

Comment: @Blindman67 `source` is not a property of `window`, it's been defined with `const`. `window.document` is not mutable, so it's ok to not call it from `window`. `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are mutable, and directly represents the Window's state, so it makes sense to refer to it as `window.innerHeight` and it's also less prone to error for future editors of the code who could otherwise think it's just a scoped variable and end up messing the whole page doing `innerWidth -= 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, clearRect works well if you don't have other elements to draw on the same canvas for each frame. However, it will not work if you only want to remove one of the elements on the canvas.

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

The other issue is that you may need some kinds of transaction effects (such as audio bar fade out) through frames for a certain element. 
If you keep drawing the effects for one element, it can clear all other elements during those frames.

The solution I came up with is to keep all elements in an array.
Then draw the array with a boolean tag that decides whether to draw or not for a certain element.

Comment: Be careful promoting your own projects, as it might be perceived as spam. See [the help center](/help/promotion) for more information